# Update deploy of web part on Sharepoint 2007

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have developed a web part and deployed it on my server using this guide:

http://leedale.wordpress.com/2007/05/31/deploying-a-webpart-solution-in-sharepoint-2007-the-simple-way/

Now I've modified my webpart and I'm not able to update it on the server. Do you have any guide to advise?
Furthermore, is the guide that I followed correct or is there a more efficient way to deploy and update custom web part on the server?
Thanks a lot

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? Are you using the Visual Studio WSS extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide you are following is for deploying a solution file to a server. While you are creating the webpart in your development environment, I wouldn't bother packaging it up each time.

Your most common development path will probably be (the "manual" way):

1. Write some code in your webpart
2. Recompile webpart
3. Install the DLL into the GAC by

   - Drag and drop from your Debug directory into the GAC (Start -> Run -> assembly)
   - OR opening the Visual Studio Command prompt and using `gacutil /i "path/to/mywebpart.dll"`
4. Run an `IISRESET` command

It is important to note that your solution already took care of registering your webpart as a safecontrol in the web.config.

When you are ready to deploy to QA or Production, you would build a release copy of your DLL and then package it up into the solution.

If you have Visual Studio 2008, I would also recommend the [Visual Studio extensions for WSS 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d87523da-b5bc-4296-be8a-8e3785c8f181). It gives you a couple templates that are very useful and allows you to write, package, and deploy a webpart in solution file all from within Visual Studio.

1. Create a new Web Part project (this is a VSeWSS project template)
2. Right click on your project's properties, go to the Debug tab, and set "Start Browser with URL" to your SharePoint site (your account will need all the necessary rights to deploy code)
3. Write some code!
4. Right click on your project and click Deploy
5. Add the web part to the site's web part gallery: `/sites/SiteCollection/_catalogs/wp`.
6. Add the web part to a page
7. Repeat #3 and #4!

Comment: Hi Kit, I tried your solution, but in my web.config the safecontrol hasen't been added. How should Visual Studio be supposed to add it? Should I specify what web site would I build the site to? Furthermore, is there a guide o tutorial to better understand Visual Studio extensions and its potential? Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi Kit, anyway your answer was very helpful, I've built my web part directly under the bin directory and I was able to update it easily and debug it.

Comment: (1.a) The safecontrol entry should be added by your solution file automatically if (defined in manifest.xml `<SafeControl Assembly="..." />`).
(1.b) Visual studio doesn't add the safe control entry automatically unless you are using the VSeWSS addon. I can't find a good post, so if you need help let me know and I can put together some steps.
(2) Glad to help! Feel free to accept my answer if it is what you needed.

Comment: Your help was great, in fact I worked out the problem in minutes. The only thing I had to do by myself was to add manually the SafeControl in the web.config. Consider that I haven't got any manifest.xml file. Should I have it in my solution? I have already installed the VSwWSS but I only use it to create template project (web parts) I really don't know how to use it extensively and I haven't find out a good article or guide...

Comment: If you use the WSS extensions, the solution file is handled automatically (when you deploy, you'll see a `\bin\Debug\solution` directory created). I updated my answer with some steps. There are also a couple other ways to build solution files: http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/articles/UsingVisualStudioAndMsBuildToCreateWssSolutions.aspx (manual way which we use) or http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/ (I hear a lot of people recommending this)